# Connecting an LCD when Pins A4 and A5 are Occupied

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

Recently I've been working on an automatic dog feeder dispenser (that dispenses by turning a screw attached to a stepper motor). Currently I have a Nema 17 connected to an L298N stepper driver which is connected to Arduino pins 9-12 and a DS1307 RTC connected to analog pins A4 and A5 (I would have a picture but the wiring is all over the place). I would like to connect a 16x2 LCD screen (with a potentiometer already on the back and 4 connecting pins) but from everything I've seen online, it also uses analog pins A4 and A5 which are occupied by the RTC. How would I go about connecting the LCD?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <RTClib.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Stepper.h>

RTC_DS1307 rtc;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F , 16 , 2);
Stepper myStepper(200 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12);

void setup() {  
  lcd.init();  
  lcd.print("yes"); 
  Wire.begin();                                           
  Serial.begin(9600);                                       
  rtc.adjust(DateTime(2021 , 7 , 15 , 3 , 23 , 0));
  myStepper.setSpeed(100);
}

void loop() {
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  Serial.print(now.hour());
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(now.minute());
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(now.second());
  Serial.println(" ");

  lcd.print(now.hour());
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.print(now.minute());
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.print(now.second());
  lcd.println(" ");

  if ((now.hour() == 7 and now.minute() == 0 and now.second() == 0)) {    
    myStepper.step(1000);

}
  delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: I2C communication lines support more than one device on the same pins, so just connect  
the LCD to the same pins... or you could just look under your Arduino to locate the 2 more I2C pins(Left of the Aref pin)

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire

Comment: I connected both the LCD and RTC to A4 and A5 via a breadboard and it works great. Thanks!

Comment: Here is one example where LCD and RTC both are conencted to same I2C pins. https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/306828496357818944

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments: Your LCD and the RTC both use the I2C bus for communication. That bus is designed to have many devices simultaneously connected. For this to work every slave device on the bus (the Arduino is the master device, which has no address) has to have a unique address. In your code you write, that the LCD is on address `0x3F`. The RTC DS1307 is `0b1101000` or `0x68` (same value in binary or hexadecimal representation) (see [the DS1307 datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1307.pdf), page 12).

So you can connect  both devices to the same pins, as the communication interface there already supports that. The pins A4 and A5 are the I2C pins of the Arduino, so you need to connect them there for using the Arduinos I2C hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my 2 cents.
As the other answer suggests, you can always use the same I2C lines for devices. The devices will be differentiated via an I2C address. I have compiled one example based on your code. [Here is the link](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/306847788434457154) to the simulation

**The code is below**

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "LiquidCrystal_I2C.h"
#include <RTClib.h>

RTC_DS1307 rtc;

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();

  if (! rtc.begin()) 
  {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    Serial.flush();
    abort();
  }

  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.print("yes");
}

void loop() {
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  Serial.print(now.hour());
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(now.minute());
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(now.second());
  Serial.println(" ");

  lcd.setCursor( 0,0);
  lcd.print(now.hour());
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.print(now.minute());
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.print(now.second());

  if ((now.hour() == 7 and now.minute() == 0 and now.second() == 0)) {
    // myStepper.step(1000);
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```

As you can see, I2C lines are shared between the RTC module and the LC display module.

[image]